# Reducing complexity of O(n^2) to at least O(n log n)

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I want to reduce complexity of this program but I don't know how.

> Program:
> You are holding an event and you need money. Every person that participates will give percentage of their salary to the event, but every person must give the same percentage. If the percentage you chose is for example 30% and person P is only willing to give 20%, then person P wont give anything. If you chose 30% and person P is willing to give 80%, then person P will only give 30%.
>
> You want to figure out what is the percentage that will get you the most money.
>
> Inputs are:
>
> First line: Number of people that participate (n)
> Next n lines: Salary of i-th person, Max percentage of salary that i-th person is willing to give away
>
> Output:
> First line: Largest amount of money that you can get for the event.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 4
> 100001 83.2
> 40001 20
> 90001 77.32
> 300001 1.88
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 146909.5464
> ```
>
> Program chose that the percentage that will bring the most money is 77.32 and wrote that the money you can get from that percentage is (100001+90001)*77.32

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int N,A[200000];
double P[200000],suma,maxsuma;

int main(){

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);

cin>>N;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    cin>>A[i]>>P[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    suma=0;
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if(P[j]>=P[i]){
            suma+=P[i]*A[j]/100.0;
        }
    }
    maxsuma=max(suma,maxsuma);
}

cout<<fixed<<setprecision(20)<<maxsuma;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dr.Watson This is the only thing that I could come up with, but I got an answer down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, sort all your people by the percentage they are willing to give descending. Now whatever percentage you pick, only some first people on the list would actually pay. Therefore, you would make the most profit-making it the last person percentage. Now also notice, that from this prefix everyone gives `salary * percentage`, so the total payment would be `total salary * percentage`. If `s[i]` is the total salary from all people up to i-th index, than `s[i] = s[i - 1] + a[i]` where a[i] is i-th person salary. Therefore you just write a loop that would first count `s[i]` using known `s[i - 1]` from the previous iteration, and then multiply it by the percentage of i-th person; across all such values pick the highest one.

I modified your code to use this idea.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int N;
std::pair<int, int> A[200000]
double maxsuma;

int main(){

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);

cin>>N;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    cin>>A[i].second>>A[i].first;
}
std::sort(A, A + N, std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>());
int suma = 0;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    suma += A[i].second;
    maxsuma=max(suma * A[i].first / 100.0, maxsuma);
}

cout<<fixed<<setprecision(20)<<maxsuma;

}
```

Comment: Hey, I have one, more general question. I have a few more problems where I have to reduce complexity, so I was wondering if you can help me out on how to approach those kinds of problems since you managed to figure out the answer to the last one pretty fast. I was searching for resources online but I couldn't find anything that could point me in the right direction on how to think about reduction of algorithm complexity.

Comment: There are many ways you can optimize your program in terms of time complexity, but there is no single approach to them. I suppose the best way to master these techniques in the practice. You may try participating in some competitive programming events, for example, https://codeforces.com/ host contests regularly, and there are others, of course.